# How can I delete a php Cookie

Tags: php, cookies

I have a `login.php` and a `logout.php` site. After the login I set a cookie, which works properly. But on the logout site I cant delete or unset the cookie.

```
login.php = setcookie($cookie_name, $cookie_value, time() + (86400 * 30), "/");

logout.php = setcookie($cookie_name, FALSE, time() - 3600);
```

After the logout page `print_r($_COOKIE)` displays a empty array,
but when I `print_r($_COOKIE)` on any other page it says the cookie exists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, there is not a way to directly delete a cookie. Just use setcookie with expiration date in the past.

```
$cookie_name = 'pontikis_net_php_cookie';
unset($_COOKIE[$cookie_name]);
// empty value and expiration one hour before
$res = setcookie($cookie_name, '', time() - 3600);
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use an empty string for the value, include the 4th parameter - domain ("/" in this case) and set a date of at least 1 day in the past (to avoid any timezone issues) when you want to unset the cookie.

```
setcookie($cookie_name, "", time() - 3600 * 24, "/");
```